# What is the lowest-energy configuration of a perfect fluid of constant angular momentum under gravity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity

What is the lowest-energy stable configuration of a perfect (homogeneous dense incompressible inviscid) non-oscillatory fluid of constant mass and angular momentum under Newtonian self-gravity?

For low values of angular momentum, I would expect this to be an oblate circular ellipsoid with its short axis as the axis of rotation, just being more oblate with faster rotation. However, for high values of angular momentum, rather than being an even flatter spheroid, perhaps a lower-energy configuration would be discontinuous—maybe a central blob with a separate ring around it?